# How to look that the strings are contained by my filename in java?

Tags: java

```
  List <String> ntfs = Arrays.asList("AUX","NUL","SOH","STX","ETX","EOT","ENQ","ACK","BEL",
    "BS","HT","VT","LF","FF","NP","CR","SO","SI","DLE","DC1","DC2","DC3","DC4","NAK","SYN",
            "ETB","CAN","EM","SUB","ESC","escape","FS","GS","RS","US","AUX", "CLOCK$", 
            "COM1","COM2","COM3","COM4","COM5","COM6","COM7","COM8","COM9" , "CON", 
            "LPT1","LPT2","LPT3","LPT4","LPT5","LPT6","LPT7","LPT8","LPT9", "NUL","PRN");
```

for example:

```
 String pathname="/path/AUX.txt";
```

So I'd like to see that in the pathname contains or not the list items, how can i do that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No comment:

```
public static boolean contains(List<String> ntfs,String pathname){ 
   for(String s:ntfs){
        if(pathname.contains(s)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `pathname="/path/AUXasdasdasdasdasd.txt";` then what will your code return?

Comment: There is no specification of this problem, there is word "contains" in OPs question @rakeb.void

Comment: I not think about it, but its good if i have AUXX.txt example is wrong...thx

Answer (score 1):

Use [`List#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method to check whether the element is present or not.

```
    List<String> ntfs = Arrays.asList("AUX", "NUL", "SOH", "STX", "ETX", "EOT", "ENQ", "ACK", "BEL", "BS", "HT", "VT", "LF", "FF", "NP", "CR", "SO", "SI", "DLE", "DC1", "DC2", "DC3", "DC4", "NAK", "SYN", "ETB", "CAN", "EM", "SUB", "ESC", "escape", "FS", "GS", "RS", "US", "AUX", "CLOCK$", "COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4", "COM5", "COM6", "COM7", "COM8", "COM9", "CON", "LPT1", "LPT2", "LPT3", "LPT4", "LPT5", "LPT6", "LPT7", "LPT8", "LPT9", "NUL", "PRN");
    String pathname = "/path/AUX.txt";
    // Take out the `AUX` part from `/path/AUX.txt` by string operations
    if (ntfs.contains(pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, pathname.indexOf(".")))) {
        System.out.println("PRESENT");
    } else {
        System.out.println("ABSENT");
    }
```

Comment: Keep in your mind it does not handle all cases. So NULL.txt will be enabled with this code. It is really depends on what do you want to achieve, maybe maskacovnik's solution would be better.

Comment: `"NULL"` is **NOT** present in the array provided by OP. Also `NULL.txt` is allowed in `NTFS`.